# Making Snake Game in Cpp Movement of Snake

Tags: c++

I'm beginner to C++. i'm making a snake game in c++ simple game console based. without using any graphics. i had done almost 60% of work the only thing which makes me confuse is the movement of snake after eating "fruit". Below is my code if someone can help me please it'll be very helpful or i want you to give me any hint so that i can continue my code

Here is my header file

**snake.h:**

```
    #ifndef SNAKE_H
    #define SNAKE_H


    class snake
    {
        private:
            char key;
int x1, y1, x2, y2, n;
            char keyp;
        public:
            snake()
            {
                x1=28; y1=12; x2=0; y2=0; n=1;
            }
            void gotoxy(int x, int y);
            void frame();
            char movement(char keyp);
            char rmove();
            char lmove();
            char umove();
            char dmove();
            void rstar();
            void rcstar();
            void options();

    };

    #endif // SNAKE_H
```

Here is my snake.cpp File

**Snake.cpp**

```
    #include "snake.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    //gotoxy function
    COORD coord={0,0};
     void snake::gotoxy(int x,int y)
     {
        coord.X=x;
        coord.Y=y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
     }

     void snake::frame()
     {
        for(int i=0;i<=78;i++)
            cout << char(45);
        for(int i=1;i<22;i++)
           {
               gotoxy(0,i);
               cout << char(124);
               gotoxy(63,i);
               cout << char(124);
               gotoxy(78,i);
               cout << char(124);
           }
           cout << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<=78;i++)
            cout << char(45);
     }

     char snake::rmove()
     {
         for(;x1<=63;x1++)
        {
            Sleep(200);
            if(x1==62)
            {
                x1=1;
                gotoxy(61,y1);
                cout << " ";
            }
            if(x1!=1)
            {
                gotoxy(x1-1,y1);
                cout << " ";
                gotoxy(x1,y1);
                cout << "*";
            }

            rcstar();
            if(kbhit())
            {
                keyp=getch();
                if(keyp=='a' || keyp=='A' || keyp=='d' || keyp=='D')
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return keyp;
     }

     char snake::lmove()
     {
         for(x1;x1>=0;x1--)
        {
            Sleep(200);
            if(x1==0)
            {
                x1=62;
                gotoxy(1,y1);
                cout << " ";
            }
            if(x1!=62)
            {
                gotoxy(x1+1,y1);
                cout << " ";
                gotoxy(x1,y1);
                cout << "*";
            }

            rcstar();
            if(kbhit())
            {
                keyp=getch();
                if(keyp=='d' || keyp=='D' || keyp=='a' || keyp=='A')
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return keyp;
     }

     char snake::umove()
     {
         for(;y1>=0;y1--)
        {
            Sleep(200);
            if(y1==0)
            {
                y1=21;
                gotoxy(x1,1);
                cout << " ";
            }
            if(y1!=21)
            {
                gotoxy(x1,y1+1);
                cout << " ";
                gotoxy(x1,y1);
                cout << "*";
            }

            rcstar();
            if(kbhit())
            {
                keyp=getch();
                if(keyp=='s' || keyp=='S' || keyp=='w' || keyp=='W')
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return keyp;
     }

    char snake::dmove()
     {
         for(;y1<=22;y1++)
        {
            Sleep(200);
            if(y1==22)
            {
                y1=1;
                gotoxy(x1,21);
                cout << " ";
            }
            if(y1!=1)
            {
                gotoxy(x1,y1-1);
                cout << " ";
                gotoxy(x1,y1);
                cout << "*";
            }

            rcstar();
            if(kbhit())
            {
                keyp=getch();
                if(keyp=='w' || keyp=='W' || keyp=='s' || keyp=='S')
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return keyp;
     }


    char snake::movement(char keyp)
    {
        switch(keyp)
        {
            case 'w':
                keyp=umove();
                break;
            case 's':
                keyp=dmove();
                break;
            case 'd':
                keyp=rmove();
                break;
            case 'a':
                keyp=lmove();
                break;
        }
        return keyp;
    }

    void snake::rcstar()
    {
        if(x1==x2 && y1==y2)
         {
             rstar();
             n++;
         }
         gotoxy(65,8);
        cout << "Score : " << n-1;
    }

    void snake::rstar()
    {
            x2 = rand()%61+1;
            y2 = rand()%21+1;
            gotoxy(x2, y2);
            cout << "*";
    }

    void snake::options()
    {
        gotoxy(64,4);
        cout << "[P] Pause";
        gotoxy(64,5);
        cout << "[K] Difficulty";
        gotoxy(64,6);
        cout << "[Q] Quit";
        gotoxy(66,9);
        cout << "High Score";
        gotoxy(70,10);
        cout << "0";
        gotoxy(66,13);
        cout << "SNAKE 2K ";
        gotoxy(65,15);
        cout << "Created By";
        gotoxy(66,17);
        cout << "Khurram";
    }
```

And Here is main main.cpp file

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "snake.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    snake a1;
    char kph;

    a1.load();
    system("cls");
    a1.frame();
    a1.gotoxy(28,12);
    cout << "*";
    a1.rstar();
    a1.options();
    kph=getch();
    do
    {
        if(kph=='w' || kph=='s' || kph=='a' || kph=='d')
            kph=a1.movement(kph);
        else if(kph=='q')
            break;
        else if(kph=='p' || kph=='P')
            kph=getch();
        else if(kph=='k' || kph=='K')
            {   kph=a1.difficulty();    }
        else
            continue;
    }
    while(kph!='q');
    a1.gotoxy(0,24);
    return 0;
}
```

First of all i want to say that i know this code is really messed up but i'm beginner and still learning how to make a good program.

Please help me to complete this program.

Comment: Could you be more specific, where are you stuck?

Comment: TL;DR! What *exactly* is your problem? Please explain it, and then narrow down the code to the parts that give you problems.

Comment: Way too much code. Please narrow it down.

Comment: To be precise narrow it down to that parts you already have debugged and where you don't understand the behavior.

Comment: You should use an *initialization list* in your constructor.  Better to learn correctly at the beginning.

Comment: Also, reduce your comparisons by 50% by converting to uppercase (`toupper`) or to lowercase (`tolower`) before comparing.

Comment: You only read a 2nd character, if the first character is `p` or `P`.  There is no `getch()` function in the `do-while` loop.  Also, don't use `getch` function because it fetches from the input *buffer*.  Some consoles require you to enter a line of text before the I/O will respond to a `getch()` function call.  Use platform specific function to get an immediate character.

Comment: the only problem i'm facing is movement of snake after eating fruit as . i'm not able to implement or you can say create any logic for the movement of snake so that after eating fruit every part of snake should follow the head this is were i'm stuck. Although the code i pasted is just to let you know this is how i'm making this program.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to save the coordinates (positions) of each segment of the snake.  You will need to prepend a head and erase a tail segment.  You will save the coordinates in a *container*.

There are many containers such as `std::vector, std::list, std::stack and std::deque.`  I recommend `std::deque`.  This allows you to push new segment coordinates into the back and pop the oldest segment from the top.

The `std::deque` structure allows growth too.  You can push more items than you pop and also pop more than push (until the container is empty).

You can also do this the more difficult method and use an array or `std::vector`.  You would erase the tail (using the coordinates at the end of the array), then move all the coordinates down (to make room for a new head coordinate), then set the first slot to the new coordinate.

Also, please invest some time with your debugger.  Debugging your program is a lot faster than using StackOverflow to debug it.  Most of us don't have the time to take your program, use a debugger, to find out where the issues are.  If the issue is not obvious to most people in the first minute, your question is less likely to be answered (thus more downvotes).

Comment: can you please explain how can i use this by giving me an example. 
i'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making 3 programs. Here is how you do it. Make good use of OOP man !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool gameOver;

const int width = 40;
const int height = 20;

int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;
int tailX[100], tailY[100];
int ntail;
enum edirecton { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
edirecton dir;


void Setup()
{
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "|";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                cout << "|";
            if (i == y && j == x)
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                cout << "F";
            else
            {
                bool print = false;
                for (int k = 0; k < ntail; k++)
                {
                    if (tailX[k] == j && tailY[k] == i)
                    {
                        cout << "o";
                        print = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!print)
                    cout << " ";
            }


            if (j == width - 1)
                cout << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "|";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Score= " << score << endl;
}

void Input()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Logic()
{
    int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    tailX[0] = x;
    tailY[0] = y;
    for (int i = 1; i < ntail; i++)
    {
        prev2X = tailX[i];
        prev2Y = tailY[i];
        tailX[i] = prevX;
        tailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;
    }
    switch (dir)
    {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    //if (x > width || x<0 || y>height || y < 0)
        //gameOver = true;
    if (x >= width)
        x = 0;
    else if (x < 0)
        x = width - 1;
    if (y >= height)
        y = 0;
    else if (y < 0)
        y = height - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ntail; i++)
    {
        if (tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y)
            gameOver = true;
    }
    if (x == fruitX && y == fruitY)
    {
        score += 10;
        fruitX = rand() % width;
        fruitY = rand() % height;
        ntail++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    Setup();
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        Sleep(80);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can alter the value in the sleep function to alter the speed of the snake.